# Application error in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Reports page in browser returns the following error. It works in Visual Studio 2008 well. Error returns not always, sometimes it works, sometimes it fails and returns the following error. Cannot understand the reason. Please, help fix this problem.

P.S.This error occurs not when I try to export report to Excel or to any other format, it returns when I run the main page where report folders are located

```
 Server Error in '/Reports' Application.

    Runtime Error 
    Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

    Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

    <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


    Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.



<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you log on the report server and execute it locally? It will display the actual error.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin, sorry for silly question, but how can I log on to report server? What do you mean by that? Can you explain this part in details? Thanks

Comment: I mean open a RDP connection to the server where the reports are hosted, then access the report via the URL `http://localhost/reports`

Comment: Another thing you might try is checking the SSRS logs for a more detailed error.   Google "SSRS log location" if you are not sure where they are for your software version.

Answer (score 1):

the answer will be in the logs...

Assuming reporting services was installed in the default location...

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles
```

My guess - datasource.